# Using for loop in python dictionary to print personal message to friends but it shows keyerror?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, keyerror

I am trying to loop through a dictionary, Which contains "friends name" and their favorite language:

```py
favourate_language = {
    'yousuf': 'python',
    'jazam': 'C',
    'abu talib': 'C++',
    'abu hurayrah': 'Go',
    'umer': 'R',
    'kasim': 'javascript'
    }
```

After that I am trying to loop through this dictionary so that when a specific name comes then a personal message will be printed for that friend:

```py
for name in favourate_language.keys():
    print(name)

# Displays personal message.
friends = ['yousuf', 'umer']

for name in favourate_language.keys():
    print(name.title())
    
    if name in friends:
        print('Assalamalaikum, ' + 
        name.title() + 
        "I see your favourate language is " + 
        favourate_language[name.title()] + "!")
```

But it shows me a keyerror for the word 'yousuf':

```py
Yousuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Farhan anwar\python\users.py", line 40, in <module>
    favourate_language[name.title()] + "!")
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'Yousuf'
```

I tried to check if the name was mispelled or capitalization mistake with the name 'yousuf', but it still shows the same error.

What I expected for the result was:

```
Yousuf
Muhammed
Assalamalaikum! Muhammed, I see your favourate language is C!
Abu Hurayrah
Ali
Assalamalaikum! Ali, I see your favourate language is Javascript!
```

But I failed to get the desired result, If you can solve this small problem?

Comment: You are looking in the dictionary for `"Yousuf"` with a capital Y. The dictionary contains `"yousuf"` (all lower-case) but not `"Yousuf"`.

Comment: Your `friends` list already has the correct keys in it. No need to modify the key when accessing the main `dict`. I think you meant to write: `favourate_language[name] + "!")`

Comment: This is a good question. +1. You have all your data. You have your whole program. You have your actual output *and* you clearly show your expected output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
favourate_language = {
'abc': 'python',
'xyz': 'C',
'abc xyz': 'C++',
'pqr mnq': 'Go',
'edc': 'R',
}
# Displays personal message.
friends = ['abc', 'edc']
for name in favourate_language.keys():
    print(name.title())
    if name in friends:
        print('Good Morning, ' + 
        name.title() + 
        "I see your favourate language is " + 
        favourate_language[name] + "!")
```

names are key in dictionary.
Do not use the method `title()` on key, it return string in title format.

```
favourate_language[name]
```